# How do I fix my string integer issue in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help to fix my code. I am trying to print a part of my string from a file named output.

```
with open('output.txt') as f:
for line in f:
    if 'UserID' in line:
        print (type(line))  
        local_var1 = line.index('UserID=\"')
        print (type(local_var1))
        #print (line)
        local_var2 = line.index('\" EntityID')
        print (type(local_var2))
        local_var3 = (line[local_var1,local_var2])
        print (local_var3)
```

But I get the following error. i have confirmed my local_var1 and local_var2 both are integers.

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "output.py", line 10, in <module>
    local_var3 = (line[local_var1,local_var2])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Output from file:

```
<User UserID="test" EntityID="000" FirstName="test1" LastName="test2" Email1="" Email2="" Email3="" />
```

Comment: You're trying to pass a tuple into the list indexer:

`line[loval_var1, local_var2]` is the same as `line[(local_var1, local_var2)]`. Did you mean for this to be a slice, using `:` instead of `,`? (e.g. `line[local_var1:local_var2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the substring, use ":", not ",".

```
local_var3 = (line[local_var1:local_var2])
```